# XQuery : use XQuery data in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, maps, xquery

My problem is the following. I declared at top of my xquery file a sequence containing some locations :

```
xquery version "1.0";
declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html";
let $locations := //location
return
```

Then I have a javascript code in my `<head>` that displays a map using Google Maps API. What I want to know is how to use my xquery variable `$locations` in my javascript function to display markers on my map ?

I used the code from http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(43.700,7.267);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom:12,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
          dataPhoto.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
-->
</script>
```

And of course in my html source :

```
<html>
   <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Zorba, JSON values can be serialized for your JS code:

```
let $obj := { "data": [1, 2, 3]}
return <script>
  var data = {serialize($obj, ())};
</script>
```

You can see this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#+Ic0lo+4mIEhji0Z0GujBQ==

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your curly braces so that your XQuery processor doesn't treat them as XQuery.  To escape a curly brace, just repeat it.  Instead of:

```
function initialize() {
```

... use:

```
function initialize() {{
```

Alternatively, you can keep your javascript intact/unmodified by referencing it in a .js file separate from your XQuery.